# Covering spaces as fiber bundles

Tags: algebraic-topology, differential-topology, fiber-bundles

I am reading Steenrod. I think there is something wrong or sloppy in his definition of a covering space as a fiber bundle. He writes:

A fibre bundle consists of:

(i) A topological space $B$ (ii) a topological space $X$   (iii) a continuous map $p: B \rightarrow X$ and (iv) a space $Y$ called the fibre. The set $Y_x$, defined by $Y_x = p^{-1}(x)$ is the fibre over $x$. It is required that each $Y_x$ be be homeomorphic to $Y$. Finally, for each $x$ in $X$, there is a neighborhood $V$ of $x$ and a homeomorphism $\phi: V \times Y \rightarrow p^{-1}(V)$ such that $p\phi(x',y)=x'$.

Later he writes:

A covering space $B$ of $X$ is another example of a bundle. The projection is the covring map. The usual definition of a covering space is the definition of bundle modified by requiring that each $Y_x$ is a discrete subspace. and ** $\phi$ is a homeomorphism of  $V \times Y_x$ with $p^{-1}(V)$ so that $\phi (x,y)=y$. **. The statement inside ** is obviously nonsense. Is it not?

Comment: The statement inside ** is obviously true. Why do you think it is nonsense?

Comment: Remember that $Y_x = p^{-1}(x)\subset p^{-1}(V)$.

Comment: @Captain Lama So for every x in V, we get the y "above" the fixed x??

Comment: @studiosus So for every x in V, we get the y "above" the fixed x??

Comment: @alireza Absolutely not. The $x$ is the previously chosen point.

Comment: Ok I was confused by his using x as a constant, I took it as a variable in the definition of phi.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It might be helpful to think of $Y_x$ as being simply an index set for the decomposition of $p^{-1}(V)$ that occurs in the definition of a covering map.

Let me use the word "sheets" for the elements of that decomposition, i.e. the "sheets" are a decomposition of $p^{-1}(V)$ into open subsets of $p^{-1}(V)$ such that the restriction of $p$ to each sheet is a homeomorphism onto $V$.

So, how do we index the sheets? Answer: the inclusion $Y_x \hookrightarrow p^{-1}(V)$ is a bijection between the set $Y_x$ and the set of sheets: each sheet contains exactly one point of $Y_x$, and each point of $Y_x$ is contained in exactly one sheet. So we can use $Y_x$ itself as an index set. Furthermore, we can topologize this set, giving it the discrete topology (which is no big deal because the subspace topology on $Y_x$ is discrete).

So now define $\phi : X \times Y_x \to p^{-1}(V)$ by letting $\phi(x',y)$ be equal to the unique point in $Y_{x'}$ such that the sheet containing $\phi(x',y)$ equals the sheet containing $y$.

Note: $x$ is a constant in this description, namely a particular point in $V$. I'm using $x'$ as a variable for an arbitrary point in $V$.

Comment: Thanks. That is what I thought but Steenrod is imprecise. As he defines Y_x, his definition is clearly wrong. I am not sure what the people are complaining about. I am not that good at math but I can see glaring carelessness when I see it and I am annoyed and confused by it. Maybe others are not. The statement strictly speaking as it is defined is wrong. Is it not?

Comment: You are not right about that issue. For example, in my answer I have used Steenrod's definition/notation two times: $Y_x = p^{-1}(x)$ for the constant point $x \in V$, and $Y_{x'} = p^{-1}(x')$ for the variable point $x' \in V$. So $Y_x$ is the "constant fiber" used in forming the domain $X \times Y_x$ of Steenrod's map $\phi$, and $Y_{x'}$ is a "variable fiber" used in writing down the formula of the map $\phi$.

Comment: $Y_x = p^{-1} (x)$ and nothing else in his definitions. The $\phi(x, y)=y$ means for every x in the product we get a point in $Y_x = p^{-1} (x)$. Think of a spiral over a circle and see that this is not correct. Do you see?

Comment: No, $\phi(x,y)=y$ means that for the **constant** $x \in V$ that was fixed, we get a point in $Y_x=p^{-1}(x)$.

Comment: That's why I was careful to introduce a separate symbol $x'$ for the variable point used as the first argument of $(x',y) \in X \times Y_x$.

Comment: hmmm ok so then if it is a you say, that particular choice for that constant defines exactly the function you describe?  .... I took it as the definition of phi for the variable x by mistake but that is how we normally define functions.

Comment: Yes, that's right. The way you see this is by the wording of Steenrod's condition in the definition of a fiber bundle: "for each $x \in X$ there is a neighborhood $V$ of $x$ and a homeomorphism $\phi : X \times Y_x \to p^{-1}(V)$..." Thus, once $x \in X$ has been chosen, it is to be regarded as a constant, and the $V$ and $\phi$ are then dependent on the choice of $x$....

Comment: In the further part of that condition, "... such that $p \phi(x',y)=x'$", now the symbols $x',y$ forming the ordered pair $(x',y) \in V \times Y_x$ are regarded as variables, namely the arguments of the function $\phi$.

Answer (score 0):

Consider a trivial cover : $B = X\times Y$ with $p: B\to X$ the first projection.

Then for all $x\in V$ we can take $V = X$ and we get $\phi_x: V\times Y_x\to p^{-1}(V)$, with $Y_x = \{x\}\times Y$ so $\phi_x: X\times (\{x\}\times Y)\to X\times Y$ defined by $\phi_x(a,(x,y)) = (a,y)$, and $\phi_x(x,(x,y)) = (x,y)$, as expected.